# Cannot use Bool in class parametrization to reverse reset polarity

Tags: scala, verilog, fpga, chisel

I just started out with Chisel and wrote a simple counter to blink an led. The FPGA board (Lattice iCEstick) has an inverted reset signal, and instead of changing the polarity in the generated verilog, I want to set it in Chisel.

I found that Module has a `_reset` parameter of type Chisel.Bool that can be set to false which inverts the reset signal. [Here](https://github.com/schoeberl/chisel-examples/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/simple/KnightRider.scala) is an example of where it is used by someone else. However I'm getting an error which I can't seem to fix. First, the code:

```
import Chisel._

class Blink( rstPol: Bool = null ) extends Module( _reset = rstPol ) {
  val io = new Bundle {
    val led = UInt( OUTPUT, 1 )
  }

  val cnt_next = UInt()
  val counter  = Reg( init = UInt( 0, 24 ), next = cnt_next )

  cnt_next := counter + UInt( 1 )

  io.led := counter( 23 )
}

object blinkmain {
  def main( args: Array[ String ] ): Unit = {
    chiselMain( Array( "--backend", "v" ),
      () => Module( new Blink( Bool( false ) ) )
    )
  }
}
```

And the error I get:

```
[error] Blink.scala:19 < /*??*/ Chisel.Bool(OUTPUT, width=1, connect to 0 inputs: ()) > doesn't have its component,yet. in class blinkmain$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1
```

If I don't supply the `Bool( false )` parameter, then I get no errors, but my reset polarity of course remains positve.

I have tried `rstPol: Bool = Bool( false )` and `Module( _reset = Bool( false ) )` but I get the same error on line 3. It seems like it's trying to assign the Bool to something that doesn't have a width, but I have no idea how that's possible.

I checked which version of Chisel I'm using and it's `2.2.33`. Here is my build.sbt file in case it's important:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel" $ "latest.version"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature", "-unchecked", "-language:reflectiveCalls")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm new to Scala and Chisel, I wrongly assumed that the `_reset` parameter of `Module` was a `Bool` to indicate whether a positive or negative reset signal would be generated. You can connect a `Bool` **INPUT** to `_reset` however, contrary to a `Bool` **OUTPUT** as the error message mentions.

This is how I fixed it (I did expand it with a counter width parameter `swidth`, but that's irrelevant):

```
import Chisel._

class Blink( swidth: Int, rst: Bool = null ) extends Module( _reset = rst ) {
  val io = new Bundle {
    val led = UInt( OUTPUT, 5 )
  }

  val counter = Reg( init = UInt( 0, width = swidth ) )

  counter := counter + UInt( 1 )

  io.led := counter( swidth - 1, swidth - 5 )
}

class Top extends Module {
  val io = new Bundle {
    val led  = UInt( OUTPUT, 5 )
    val rstn = Bool( INPUT )
  }

  val rst   = Reg( next = Reg( next = !io.rstn ) )
  val blink = Module( new Blink( 27, rst ) )

  blink.io.led <> io.led
}

object BlinkMain {
  def main( args: Array[ String ] ): Unit = {
    chiselMain( Array( "--backend", "v", "--targetDir", "verilog" ),
      () => Module( new Top() )
    )
  }
}
```

So I created a `Top` module that instantiates the `Blink`, which takes the inverted reset input (`rstn`), inverts it, and assigns that to `_reset`. For good measure, I also route `rstn` through two flip-flops to sync it up with the input clock signal.